# Python: Why am I not able to use the functions of cv2?

Tags: python, opencv, attributes, package, interpreter

Can you help me why am I not able to use the functions of cv2? I installed opencv-contrib-python package and I have Python3.9 on my computer. I do not understand.

Picture of the problem:

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure pycharm, press ctrl + alt + S to open the project settings click add and select your virtual env.
This is better explained here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env

Comment: I have installed it correctly into the environment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading opencv version to 4.5.5.62:

Ctrl + alt + S => Python interpreter => opencv-python (click on it to select it) and
press the - sign at the top to uninstall.

Then, open the terminal and type:

```
pip install opencv-python===4.5.5.62
```

Then, in you python script import as follows:

```
import cv2.cv2
```

Comment: `cv2.cv2` is a **bug** and should **never** be used.

Comment: **cv2.cv2** is the only way (in some instances) to get it to work due to its poor way of importing
Other posts suggest instead using **from cv2 import cv2** but it didn't work in my case

Comment: those "some instances" should be debugged then. it should always just be `import cv2 as cv` (because "cv2" is an accident of history and it should always be called `cv`)